# Laravel 5.5 'No scheduled commands are ready to run.'

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, schedule, laravel-scheduler

I have a Laravel 5.5 installation and am trying to get the scheduler to run.  I have the following cron job running and it is working fine.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/project1/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/project1/schedule.log
```

The cron job is outputting to a log file and I get the same result in cron as I get if I run artisan schedule:run from the command line.  The result is always the same and says no scheduled commands are ready to run.  The problem doesn't appear to be with cron as the job runs and I get output.

I configured the simple artisan inspire command to run in the Laravel schedule function.  I can run the inspire command on the command line with php artisan inspire and it works fine.  I understand all the posts about timezone but it is not a timezone issue, the command simply doesn't run ever.  I am also not using withoutOverlapping(), so that is not my problem.  So I have a cron job running every minute to run the laravel schedule and it does output to my log, which indicates that cron and Laravel are communicating.  I think the problem must be that Laravel doesn't think there is a command that needs to be executed.  I don't know how to debug this any further so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code from your `App\Console\Kernel.php` file.

Comment: i found the solution in my case it was APP_ENV and app_debug , they were used in routes and clearing view cache , some where you must be using those variables and clearing out something which is required by scheduler , kindly check